# I want to install nodejs in my shared hosting using gitbash

Tags: node.js, git-bash

I amusing a shared hosting and i want to install node.js in the server, please suggest me commands that need to be used for the installation.

I have tried following commands

`git clone https://github.com/ry/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install`

it is giving me "-bash: sudo: command not found" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting will almost certainly not grant you root access, so that won't work. Potentially you might be able to use nvm, but I seriously doubt you could actually use it in production to run a Node.js app.

Shared hosting is generally for things like Wordpress and isn't really an option for Node.js. A VPS is the way to go. Don't waste your time trying to get shared hosting working for this use case because it's not worth it.